# my own 'share it' plugin

Tags: javascript, html

```
textarea onclick="this.focus(); this.select();" rows="1" cols="100" readonly="readonly" style="background: #ffffcc; font-family: Monospace;">
a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/ajax/share?url=......" onclick="window.open(this.url, 'blabla', 'width=600,height=400');">
/textarea>
```

I want to make some kind of plugin like Twitter did. I mean this easiest one 'Tweet this.'
This is a code for paste but I do not now how to take the url of the current website. maybe a javascript but how ? Could you modify my code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get url of current page from window.location.href:

```
<button onclick="window.open('http://myUrl?from='+window.location.href)">
    Click!
</button>
```